# boost serialization for void* pointer type does not compile

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

i need to serialize a simple struct which has a pointer of type void * but when i serialize it gives error **"C2338: boost::serialization::tracking_level< T >::value != boost::serialization::track_never" pointing to shared_ptr.hpp at line 167** . Below is the code

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/optional.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

  struct Man
   {

       Man();
       virtual ~Man();


      std::list<boost::shared_ptr<void *>> condition; 

   private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
         ar & condition;  // if i comment this line.. issue goes away.. 
      } 
   };

   struct SuperMan
   {
   public:
      SuperMan(void);
      SuperMan(const parameter_strings & parms);

      virtual ~SuperMan(void);


      boost::optional<anyURI> detail;
      boost::optional<SuperManInfo> SuperMan_info;            

   private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
         ar & SuperMan_info;
         ar & detail;
      } 

   };
```

does really boost supports the serialization of void* pointer and if yes.. is member variable seriazed in wrong way ?

Comment: Assuming this is your real code: If you want to be able to serialize that variable, you have to somehow tell boost::serialization what the `void*` actually is pointing too.  From serialization's point of view, it's a generic pointer, and it has no clue what to do with it.  If it's an example (And I hope it is, because a `shared_ptr<void*>` is a TERRIBLE idea), then we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

No Boost Serialization does not support serialization of `void*`. For the simple reason that there's no type information so it cannot possibly tell **what** should be serialized.

Serializing the value that the pointer happens to have is completely useless, as on most platforms this is just a temporary address in the context of the running process and when you read it back, that value will be meaningless.

For this reason, `shared_ptr<void*>` is a useless idea too. (Unless, perhaps, `void*` is actually some kind of opaque HANDLE and you used a custom deleter to free the resource corresponding to that handle: [Rule Of Zero article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)).

So, figure out what's reallyin your `condition` collection. Fix the type to reflect that, or manually fix the serialization code to cast and otherwise force the inclusion of relevant data in the archive.

Comment: condition needs to point to X type of variables. Can we use it like shared_ptr<X *> condition and then serialize it